# Why did the UK ban phenmetrazine?

Tags: medications, social-anxiety, stimulants, health-policy, class-schedule-of-drugs

I used small doses everyday for years, it's the only thing that made my social disorders bearable. I wasn't breaking any laws.

Why did the (UK) government *recently* ban phenmetrazine when they formerly tolerated its use?

Answer (score 1):

As correctly asserted, [it is banned class B stimulant un the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/controlled-drugs-list--2/list-of-most-commonly-encountered-drugs-currently-controlled-under-the-misuse-of-drugs-legislation#fn:1). In fact [it was banned in 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drugs_controlled_by_the_UK_Misuse_of_Drugs_Act#Class_B_drugs) so I am unsure why you think the ban was recent.

If you have social disorders and live in the UK you can ask for a referral from your doctor. Most common route is medication coupled with therapy (group or solo).

To **why** it was banned is a deeper question. When the misuse act was drawn up it pulled together substances that were known to be used to a 'high'. Primarily in Sweden it was abused for the high it gives leading to [classification as a narcotic in 1959](http://druglibrary.org/schaffer/LIBRARY/studies/cu/CU39.html)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which concerns *why* phenmetrazine was banned.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist at some level that is a deeper, unanswerable, question. Staying brief, it was banned because it was abused for the high, primarily in Sweden where it was classified as a narcotic in 1959 http://www.druglibrary.org/schaffer/LIBRARY/studies/cu/CU39.html

Comment: Mind editing the answer to include the above, and references?